# how to acess data using web service, getting error in connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am working with asp.net web services using c# need to access the database in web service but getting error in connection string can any one tell me how to specify the connections string of database here..
 here is my code here I am using connection string as i use the string in web form..I am beginner so please  guide me in step by step manner or reffer any clear and easily understandable manner as I could not get the point how connection sting is being specified in no of tutorials..

```
 [WebMethod(Description = "show student data")]
public DataSet values(int a)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"].ConnectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from STUDENT where stdID='"+a+"'", con);
      SqlDataReader r;
      r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      r.Read();
      foreach
      return r;
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from STUDENT where stdID='" + a + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ada.Fill(ds);
    return ds;


}
```

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: perhaps you should be setting... User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Comment: You need to post the error message.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: here is complete error message

Comment: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Code.gv5utt06
  StackTrace:
       at WebService.values(Int32 a) in c:\Users\hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Webservice_Web\App_Code\WebService.cs:line 40
  InnerException:

Answer (score 0):

Here your just to provide name of connection string in .ConnectionStrings[""] bracket and put your connection string in web.config file as per below.

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Dbconnection" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" ;
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

add this connection string in configuration manager tag in web.config file and write following connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
```

add in comment if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is a bit wrong... try something like

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PUTYOURDATABASENAMEHERENOTTHEFILENAME;Integrated Security=True;User ID=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword");
```

"The User Instance feature is deprecated with SQL Server 2012, use the SQL Server Express LocalDB feature instead." https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I am bignner would you please guide me from where can i find default userId  and password as I didn't set any id and password

Comment: Try the string without the user id and password... failing that set a breakpoint in your code and debug it... you can attach to the service process.